# confirm-bootstrap.js - ASP.Net vb.net behind code - Trigger .js and get reply from client

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

My first screen has 2 textboxes and a dropdown using ASP.Net and Bootstrap v3.3.5

Part of the frontend looks like this..

```
    v--------<Snip>--------v

         <p>
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-med-4">
         <div class="text-left">
         <label>Order</label>

         <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrimOrd" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Primary Reference" MaxLength="30" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecOrd" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Secondary Reference" MaxLength="20" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

        <label>Delivery</label>
    ^--------<Snip>--------^

    Behind code looks like this..
    v--------<Snip>--------v
       If Not IsPostBack Then
         'Setup session detail
        Else
    Try

     Dim PB As String = Right(" " & Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"), 6)

     If PB = "rimOrd" Then
                'Get SQL to lookup existing ref - return summary if found

      Dim ChkPrim As String = ExistAspOrderHDR_ORDERREF("BL", txtPrimOrd.Text)
      If Trim(ChkPrim).Length > 0 Then
      Session.Contents("MyBad") = "rimOrd"

**'Here call error -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
                'js is at ../Scripts/confirm-bootstrap.js
                 $('#myLinkToConfirm').confirmModal({
                 confirmTitle : 'Custom please confirm',
                 confirmMessage : 'Custom are you sure you want to perform this action ?',
                 confirmOk : 'Custom yes',
                 confirmCancel : 'Cutom cancel',
                 confirmDirection : 'rtl',
                 confirmStyle : 'primary'
                 confirmCallback : defaultCallback,
                 confirmDismiss : true,
                 confirmAutoOpen : false
                 });**
'Here call error -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
      Else
          txtSecOrd.Focus()
      End If
 End If

 If PB = "SecOrd" Then
  ddlQCode.Focus()
 End If
```

^----------------^

I found a .js at 'http://maxailloud.github.io/confirm-bootstrap/#' called "confirm-bootstrap" and looks great in the demo.
I want to give the user plenty of detail of why they can not use that reference, who has used it, when...
OR the option to edit the entry if they have just come back to complete it.
[Re-Try] or [Continue Edit] .

AND make the error obvious not just a beep 'Error near..'

How can I make this or some message popup in the users face then read what their reply was?
Is there a way in general to call a script using behind code?

I hope this is clear and I have not also failed to get the question correct.

Thanks.